# MonoGame for iOS - getting started

Tags: ios, monogame

I can't find any clear directions on how to get started. I only see a Windows installer for MonoGame but what little documentation I've found seems to say you install it on the Mac and do the work there. If someone could simply tell me which parts go where that would be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MonoDevelop, you can get started. What really helped me get started though was taking a look at the StarterKits. If you look [here](https://github.com/kungfubanana/MonoGame-StarterKits) and just download the repository you'll find lots of nice iOS examples. Those should get you on your way!

In terms of setting up your environment, just install MonoDevelop on your Mac and checkout (or just download a ZIP of) [this](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop3d) repo. Build in MonoDevelop. You should make a folder called StarterKits and place the previous repo in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

On their site in the downloads section, if you look just above the windows installer download link, there is just a zip file with the project, you just download and extract that. Then you can open up in MonoDevelop

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is based on MonoTouch. You can find general MonoTouch guidance here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios

Comment: link only answer